# Jekyll Pagination Path Doesn't Include Page Number

Tags: ruby, pagination, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I am attempting to create pagination in Jekyll under the path '/notes/'.

In my `_config.yml`, I have:

```
paginate: 2
paginate_path: "/notes/:num/"
```

In my `/notes/index.html`, I have:

```
<div class="pagination">
  {% if paginator.previous_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.previous_page_path }}" class="previous section link">Previous</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="previous section link">Previous</span>
  {% endif %}
  <span class="page_number section">{{ paginator.page }} / {{ paginator.total_pages }}</span>
  {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a href="{{ paginator.next_page_path }}" class="next section link">Next</a>
  {% else %}
    <span class="next section link">Next</span>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

When I load `http://localhost:4000/notes`, I see that the 'Previous' link is not linking to `/notes/2`, but instead it simply links to `/notes/`, the page that I am already on. Additionally, when looking in the generated `_site` folder, I see that `/notes/2` has not been created, despite having more than two posts created.

So, I suppose my question is, how can I fix this and get jekyll to paginate properly?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having a similar issue.